# Can I put a SqlParameter source a column from another table?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sqlconnection

I got 2 tables: `product` with `pid` primary key and `costs` with `pid` foreign key referencing `product.pid`

DG -data adapter

```
DG.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from costs where pid=@pid",con);
SqlParameter param= DG.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pid",  SqlDbType.Int, 4, "pid"));
param.SourceColumn = "pid" 
param.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;
DG.Update(ds, "costs");
```

Where it uses the `param.SourceColumn = "pid"` from `costs`, I would like it to take the `pid` from the `product` table as I want this to get all child rows of the `cost` table.

Comment: Parameter is expecting a single value not entire column What is your intent here? Depending on your answer you might want to rewrite it as `JOIN`

Comment: Your scalar SelectCommand needs to be executed before any values will be available.